# Get differences between folders

Tags: diff, directory

I need to get only the files that are not part of the framework I'm using. I can get a fresh copy of the framework into another folder to diff against; that's probably a good way to do it. If this is the X/Y problem, let me know.

How do I diff two folders against each other? I want changed files to be copied into another folder, in the same relative file structure.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS X, but linux or windows solutions are fine too.

Comment: Linux and OSX are similar enough, but a solution for Windows would likely not work on Linux or OSX. ;)

Comment: Many linux solutions work in cygwin or mingw on windows :) It's trickier the other way around, but since I have multiple computers, I can run the program on one of them and move the result over.

Comment: Yes, true. But if you leave it open to "Windows" you might get a solution from someone using Windows PowerShell which wouldn't help you at all. Cygwin only helps you the other direction: someone gives you a Linux solution and you want to run it on Windows. Something kind of quick and I didn't get a chance to test it, but change to the parent directory of the first folder, the do something like: `find . -type f -exec "diff {} other/{} && cp -a {} diffdir/ > /dev/null" ;`

Comment: Oops but without the quotes around the command.

Comment: But I do have a windows computer I could run that powershell solution on :) I'll try your code tomorrow.

Comment: Alternatively: `find . -type f -exec diff {} other/{} \; -exec cp -a {} diffdir/ \; > /dev/null`